# What is the point of using set and reset in JK Flip Flop?

Tags: flipflop

Here is the scheme of a JK flip flop.

I know what does asynchronous reset and set, but why would we use them? In what scenarios it is needed?

[image]

Comment: how about a power-on reset?

Answer (score 2):

You may want a simple way to force a known state at power up or in recovery from a fault.

Also, many digital systems, even if synchronous internally, have asynchronous interfaces. Logic to capture an external pulse might use the asynchronous set function (got a pulse) together with a synchronous clear (processed it).

Answer (score 1):

The normal uses of the async inputs are start-up and override conditions which occur in between clocks.  However, many applications don't need this, which is why many/most J-K flips flops don't have async set/reset.